# Should I use one thick wire or many thin wires in a step-up high frequency transformer to reduce resistance and impedance?

Tags: current, transformer, resistance, impedance, step-up

I am planning to make a step up high frequency (hundreds of kHz) transformer. I want to reduce the resistance and impedance in the secondary. Should I use one thick wire in the secondary, or should I wind many thin wires in the secondary to reduce its resistance?

Due to skin effect, the AC current flows on the surface so a thick wire will have lower surface area than many thin wires.  That's what made me think I should use many thin wires than a thick wire in the secondary.

Comment: What frequency are we talking about?

Comment: How thick wire(s) do you need?

Comment: Generally there are bigger problems than skin effect in HF transformers. We only usually use multistrand wire to improve resistance for high Q filter coils, as the benefits are minimal in conventional transformers. If it's for efficiency, losses tend to be dominated by the core. If it's for output impedance, that tends to be dominated by leakage inductance. Leakage inductance must usually remain higher than is otherwise ideal to reduce self capacitance, and to allow room for high voltage insulation. Many more details about power and voltage levels, and why the requirement, for a good answer.

Comment: If you do go the route of multi-strand, be aware that there is commercially available multi-strand magnet wire known as Litz wire.

Comment: The same thing that causes skin effect still causes it when cut up the wire into smaller wires - in a circular bundle of wires, the middle wire won't get as much current